# JsonPath: How to check if a field has some value or not through JsonPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am finding it a little difficult to understand how to write a jsonpath that will tell me whether there is some value present or not in the field.

For example: Consider this json:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

And if I write: $.phoneNumbers[?(@.type.length>0)]

It gives me this result:

```
'0' ...
  'type' => "iPhone"
  'number' => "0123-4567-8888"
'1' ...
  'type' => "home"
  'number' => "0123-4567-8910"
```

I did this here: http://jsonpath.com/

So if suppose I want to know if there is any value in the number field inside the phonenumber or if it's empty , then what should be my jsonpath? I tried various things, but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: No answers yet. :(

Answer (score 10):

You may use the exists-filter `?(@.<field>)` like so

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.number)].number
```

This will give you all numbers with any non-null value are, i.e.

```
"phoneNumbers": [
{
  "type"  : "iPhone",
  "number": "0123-4567-8888"
},
{
  "type"  : "home",
  "number": ""
}]
```

will only return the first result

```
'0' => "0123-4567-8888"
```

regardless whether the `number`-field is completely missing, `null` or an empty string `""`.

I learned this from some of Newtonsoft.Json's JPath-Unit-Tests, cf.: [JPathExecutTests.ExistsQuery()](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/1584588f031e6d8839d41a4273ed242d84699b06/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Linq/JsonPath/JPathExecuteTests.cs#L850-L858)

Comment: This is great, could you extend your answer to include a way to filter for the first result where attribute is not null? Our API returns a lot of results, and I need a way to take the first "not empty" (or in our case not null) result (which there are normally many of)

Comment: Selecting the first element of an expression is an open issue and seems not be possible right now. Some workarounds are mentioned, though, cf.: 

- https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272
- http://jsonpath.com/